# A DIY question / handlebar / build

Tags: handlebars, handlebar-tape

I'm looking to replicate the montage in the photo, which involves attaching an epoxy beam to a bicycle handlebar (it's a science project), as I show in the drawing.  The beam must be very well fixed to maximize its vibrations.  do you have an idea to achieve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: 3D print some kind of bracket like the one shown in the photo and drawing? On a bigger, treadless stem you might be able to just tie a metal (or wooden) plate to the stem with zip ties. I’ve done so to mount a navigation device.

Comment: Are you trying to power the LED light with electricity generated from vibrations?  If so, consider a clamp where the unsupported length can be "tuned" either by adding/removing weights, or simply by adjusting the unsupported length.  I suspect you're looking for some kind of resonant frequency on a specific type of road surface.

Comment: @Criggie Do you have any idea of any type of clamp?

Comment: Does it have to be on the handle bar and is the bike one picture yours? Asking some (touring) bikes have mounting points (M5 screws) on the fork, or it can also be fixed on the luggage carrier or on the bottle carrier points. The advantage there is that it would be mounted straight on the frame, so vibrations can be maximised. If the bike depicted is not yours and the handlebar allows it, the stem cap can also be an option: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WI1FX22PIvc

Answer (score 1):

I think your sketch is great.  However use slots instead of holes for the screws, so you can tune the length, to aim for a resonant frequency at the speed you want to ride.

Simplify it by using two saddle clamps instead of the pictured round thing.
Saddle clamps are often used for securing pipe to a wall.

One of your main problems will be rotation over time - the front will drop down like a cheap headlight.  If your handlebars are steel, then consider drilling into them and using one additional bolt to prevent rotation.  You could also weigh as much behind the bars as you do in front, so they are "balanced".

You can hang the beam below the bars too - it doesn't have to be on top. Mind out for knee-strike though if its off to the side.

Lastly does this need to be on the bars?  You could secure the device to the stem so it points straight out the front in the middle, which gives more material to buttress the unsupported arm out the front.  This might help with cable snagging while turning.

Comment: Drilling into your handlebar, even if it’s steel, is probably extremely unsafe. OP would be better off just clamping harder, perhaps with some carbon paste.

Comment: @MaplePanda No - steel should be fine for drilling a small antirotation bolt.  Its not carbon, its not aluminium.   Another way to reduce rotation is to clamp a hard steel rod between clamp and bar, which will subtly deform both which provides some tooth.